# How to docker-compose up official wordpress latest image in php version 8?

Tags: php, wordpress, docker-compose

I am using [dockers official wordpress image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) to deploy local wordpress environments using [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

After running `docker-compose up -d` and then running [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) function in my local theme code, the current running php version is `7.4`...

[image]

But if you look at the [official wordpress image repo on github](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/tree/5bbbfa8909232af10ea3fea8b80302a6041a2d04/latest), you can see the latest wordpress version supports php version 8.0...

[image]

My question is, how can I deploy my wordpress docker image using `php8.0`?

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file...

```yml
version: '3.7'

networks:
  wordpress:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.0.0/16

services:

  # here is our mysql database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
     - ./db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
     #- ./docker/db-dumps:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:delegated
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wordpress

  # here is our wordpress server
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      # our persistent local data re routing
      - ./themes/example:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/example:delegated
      - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./mu-plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins
      - ./uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wordpress
    environment:

      # our local dev environment
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1

      # docker wp-config settings
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |

        /* development parameters */
        define('WP_CACHE', false);
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'local');

        /* configure mail server */
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_AUTH', false);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_SECURE', '');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_HOST', 'mailhog');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PORT', '1025');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_USERNAME', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PASSWORD', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM', 'no-reply@example.com');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM_NAME', 'Example');

        if(!defined('WP_HOME')) {
          /* force our home url */
          define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost');
          define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME);
        }

  # here is our mailhog server
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"
    networks:
      - wordpress
```

How do I define which php version to use from the [wordpress:latest](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/tree/5bbbfa8909232af10ea3fea8b80302a6041a2d04/latest) image, so every time I `docker-compose up -d` it uses the [php8.0](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/tree/5bbbfa8909232af10ea3fea8b80302a6041a2d04/latest/php8.0) version?

Any ideas or advice would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I *think* WordPress only officially supports up to 7.4. If you visit https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/references/php-compatibility-and-wordpress-versions/ you'll see that php 8 is classified as “beta support” with a more detailed explanation at https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/23/wordpress-and-php-8-0/ as well as this GitHub issue https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/540#event-4230950352

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current wordpress:latest is on 7.4 but you can use one of the [supported tags](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) in your docker-compose file.
In my case I used `image: wordpress:6.0-php8.1-apache`

Comment: Thanks for this yes, I actually sorted this in the end using the same tag, I didn't understand how to use tags back then but now I am using them  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Duncan you need a tagged version

```
image: wordpress:6.0.2-php8.0-apache
```

Note: If your wordpress crashes and burns when you run it you can `composer down` and change it back again. It is best to disable any plugins and non official themes before switching as they could contain old code that is likely to not work on the latest php version.

Comment: Great pointers. I am only experimenting WP in PHP8 locally. I am not migrating anything yet because I've done some server tests on current staging sites in PHP8, and I get a ton of deprecated logs in `WP_DEBUG` mode from plugins (even premium plugins like Gravity Forms which is annoying) and also even some composer vendor packages in my theme are returning deprecated notices. I am cautiously testing local theme dev from scratch in PHP lang level 8.1 using my IDE to guide me through coding 'warning free' PHP syntax, which is taking some getting used to. Thanks for posting on my question. 